# Function external and internal parameter not mutable

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm new in Swift and i have a question it can be wrong question

```
func multiplyNumber(number myNumber: inout Int) -> Int {
    myNumber *= 7;
}
multiplyNumber(number: 7);
```

This function return this error

> cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: literals are not
>   mutable

Comment: Why are you using an `inout` parameter when you have a return value?

Comment: You're passing in 7. You need to pass in a variable. Numbers (7) can't be assigned

Comment: When I want to change myNumber parametr this return 
left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'myNumber' is a 'let' constant

Comment: @StephenJ Yeah i understand this part this is inout problem seven is not changeable

Comment: @StephenJ i have second question  i want write look like this method how i can do it

func multiplyNumberOtherWay(number myNumber: Int) -> Int {
    myNumber*=7;
    return myNumber;
}

Comment: It's how you call it. Not how you write it. 
var aNumber = 7; multiplyNumber(aNumber); aNumber is the inout parameter. inout means "will be changed". 7 can't be used.

Comment: But i want  look like this code without inout how can i do ?
multiplyNumberOtherWay(number myNumber: Int) -> Int { myNumber*=7; return myNumber; } 
multiplyNumberOtherWay(7)